# assign function to generic delegate

Tags: c#, generics, delegates, assign

i have a generic class in which i want to save a delegate that uses Type T as argument and return value. How do i assign a method to the attribute getValueDefault?

```
private delegate TOut GetValueDefault<in TIn, TOut>(string key, TIn defaultValue);

private GetValueDefault<T, T> getValueDefault = null;
```

For example a method with the signature `bool ThirdPartyClass.foo(string key, bool defValue)`

Comment: What is the generic argument passed as `T` in this instance?  Unless it's `object`, I don't think this will be possible as `string` and `bool` are not mutually compatible with any other type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as easy as:

```
private delegate TOut GetValueDefault<in TIn, TOut>(string key, TIn defaultValue);

private GetValueDefault<int, bool> getValueDefault = afoo;

static bool ThirdPartyClass.foo(string key, int defValue)
{
    \\...
}
```

However, if *in all situations you are going to have equal in and out type parameters*, you may simplify it to:

```
private delegate T GetValueDefault<T>(string key, T defaultValue);

private static GetValueDefault<bool> getValueDefault = afoo;
```

Comment: this only works for `bool`, if `T` is something else, i want to assign `(int) ThirdPartyClass.foo2(string key, int defaultValue)` in the constructor.

Comment: @MatthiasSchl I've updated my answer, for it to work with input parameter of type `int`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write something like this:

```
class Sample<T>
{
    public delegate TOut GetValueDefault<in TIn, TOut>(string key, TIn defaultValue);

    private GetValueDefault<T, T> getValueDefault = null; 
    public Sample(GetValueDefault<T, T> del)
    {
        getValueDefault = del;
    }
}
```